# Z-index not working on div on fixed position header

Tags: css, z-index, master-pages

I have a page using a masterpage in asp.net 4.0. My masterpage has header which has a search box. Header has css position fixed and have z-index 10.

I am trying to create a search instruction which will open when user types anything. my instruction box do not show as floatig over header instead it opens inside header and expands it. Here are my css and html

```css
header {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#ef4023;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
}

header #Guide {
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 5;
         margin-right: -1px;
 position:relative;
        background: #eee;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;

    }
```

```html
<header>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>
            </div>
     <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-8">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!--SearchBarStart-->
                    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

                        <form>
                            <h3>Search Here </h3>


                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SearchKeyword" ng-model="searchText" required="required" />

                            <div class="list-group" id="Guide" ng-show="showLinks">

                                <a class="list-group-item" href="" ng-click="SearchType(0,true,'KeyWord', 1)">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="fa fa-suitcase"></span><span style="padding-left: 20px">instruction goes here</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
               </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
   </header>
```

Comment: I have also tried z-index greater for element #guide. but that also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `position: fixed` also on the instruction box, with according position settings. (`relative` will put it into the document flow, thereby taking up space, and `absolute` won't work since you don't have a relative parent for it.)

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ef4023;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}

header #Guide {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 15;
  margin-right: -1px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 110px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-8">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <!--SearchBarStart-->
      <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        <form>
          <h3>Search Here </h3>


          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SearchKeyword" ng-model="searchText" required="required" />

          <div class="list-group" id="Guide" ng-show="showLinks">

            <a class="list-group-item" href="" ng-click="SearchType(0,true,'KeyWord', 1)">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="fa fa-suitcase"></span><span style="padding-left: 20px">instruction goes here</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>`
```